# How do I affect a previousSibling style on onmouseover event. CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, onmouseover

I created a map using inline SVG. The each district lights up on hover (solved with CSS). What I want to achieve is that when the corresponding districts name is hovered, the district should light up as well.

I wasn't able to achieve this with CSS3 since it does not have a previousSibling selector. Neither could I change the markup structure so the district comes after the title. Why? because then the text is behind the district. (Using the z-index hasn't worked either.)

I then hoped to find a solution with Javascript using the onmouseover event to trigger a function that would the previousSibling of the currently hovered text, to change its style.

Part of my markup:

```
<path class="district-map" d="M264.741,21.661,323.1,155.235l179.3,85.439L496.992,21.661Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
<text onmouseover="myFunction()" class="district-text" transform="translate(349 99)">
    <tspan x="0" y="0">District 5</tspan>
</text>
```

Here the CSS:

```
path.district-map {
    fill: green;
}
path.district-map:hover {
    fill: white;
}
```

At last the Javascript:

```
function myFuntion() {
    var district = this.previousSibling;
    district.style.fill = "#fff";
}
```

[Link to my codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBQpWb)

What am I missing here, what's not working right?
(I am a complete noob at JavaScript btw)

Thank you for your input.

Full Snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        svg {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <defs>
            <style>
              path.district-map {
                    fill: #00ff90;
                    transition: fill 0.2s;
                }
                path.district-map:hover {
                    fill: #fff;
                }
                .district-text {
                    fill: #5b5b5b;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    font-family: SegoeUI, Segoe UI;
                }
                .container  {
                    fill: #d1d1d1;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
              function myFuntion() {
                 var district = this.previousSibling;
                 district.style.fill = "#fff";
}
            </script>
        </defs>
            <rect class="container" width="500" height="500"/>

            <path class="district-map" d="M264.741,21.661,323.1,155.235l179.3,85.439L496.992,21.661Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
            <text class="district-text" onmouseover = "myFunction()" transform="translate(349 99)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 5</tspan></text>

            <path class="district-map" d="M51.745,21.661V149.82l108.9,95.668L272.563,94.465l-28.279-72.8Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
            <text class="district-text" onmouseover = "myFunction()" transform="translate(87 112)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 4</tspan></text>

            <path class="district-map" d="M51.745,179.3l100.481,81.227L131.167,289.41l178.1,187.124H51.745Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
            <text class="district-text" onmouseover = "myFunction()" transform="translate(75 414)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 3</tspan></text>

            <path class="district-map" d="M429,217.81l75.812,43.321v210.59l-181.107,3.61L297.232,442.84Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
            <text class="district-text" onmouseover = "myFunction()" transform="translate(374 379)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 2</tspan></text>

            <path class="district-map" d="M284,109.507,155.235,285.2,291.817,427.8l125.752-216-107.1-49.338Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
            <text class="district-text" onmouseover = "myFunction()" transform="translate(226 272)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 1</tspan></text>
    </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Your codepen does not include the javascript code.
Also, you can add a code snippent in your question, no need for external links.

Comment: i just realized my codepen didn't save. thanks for the notice. changing it right now

Comment: add `text{pointer-events:none}` to your css

Answer (score 1):

Just group/wrap together district + text using SVG `<g>` element ([more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g)), than change CSS to react on group hover:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 500px;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
   <defs>
    <style>
     path.district-map {
      fill: #00ff90;
      transition: fill 0.2s;
     }
     g:hover path.district-map {
      fill: #fff;
     }
     .district-text {
      fill: #5b5b5b;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: SegoeUI, Segoe UI;
     }
     .container  {
      fill: #d1d1d1;
     }
     
    </style>
   </defs>
    <rect class="container" width="500" height="500"/>
    
        <g>
    <path class="district-map" d="M264.741,21.661,323.1,155.235l179.3,85.439L496.992,21.661Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
    <text class="district-text" transform="translate(349 99)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 5</tspan></text>
      </g>
    
   <g> 
      <path class="district-map" d="M51.745,21.661V149.82l108.9,95.668L272.563,94.465l-28.279-72.8Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
    <text class="district-text" transform="translate(87 112)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 4</tspan></text>
      </g>
    
    <g>
          <path class="district-map" d="M51.745,179.3l100.481,81.227L131.167,289.41l178.1,187.124H51.745Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
    <text class="district-text" transform="translate(75 414)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 3</tspan></text>
      </g>
    
    <g>
          <path class="district-map" d="M429,217.81l75.812,43.321v210.59l-181.107,3.61L297.232,442.84Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
    <text class="district-text" transform="translate(374 379)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 2</tspan></text>
      </g>
    
    <g>
          <path class="district-map" d="M284,109.507,155.235,285.2,291.817,427.8l125.752-216-107.1-49.338Z" transform="translate(-21 7)"/>
    <text class="district-text" transform="translate(226 272)"><tspan x="0" y="0">District 1</tspan></text>
      </g>
      
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Updated PEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XxZRRb).

> The `<g>` SVG element is a container used to group other SVG elements.

Comment: thank you that did the trick. i overthought the whole thing too much. such a simple fix :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the solution with CSS by @skobaljic, but if you really want to use the js, following is the example code:

```
const textElement = document.querySelector('.district-text');
textElement.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.fill = '#fff';
});
textElement.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    e.target.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.style.fill = '#00ff90';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think none of the proposed solutions work.
You need to set mouse event handlers on the main map chunks and have these change the attributes of the path and of the text. Like this:

```
window.onload=function () {
    var districts = document.getElementsByClassName("district-map");
    console.log(districts);

    var overAction = function() {
        var district = this;
        var disctrictText = district.nextSibling.nextSibling;
        district.style.fill = "#fff";
        disctrictText.style.fill = "#f00";
    }

    var outAction = function() {
        var district = this;
        var disctrictText = district.nextSibling.nextSibling;
        district.style.fill = "#00ff90";
        disctrictText.style.fill = "#000";
    }

    for (var i=0; i < districts.length; i++) {
        districts[i].onmouseover = overAction;
        districts[i].onmouseout = outAction;
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyYder

And remove the :hover css.

-- EDIT: --

The call to .nextSibling was failing because somehow this is wrapped inside another "ghost" element... hence the .nextSibling.nextSibling call.